# MySQLi LEFT JOIN query is throwing a syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, left-join

I have two tables 'lr_users' and 'lr_ranks' with the following table structures:

> **lr_users:**
>   user_id(pk), username, rank(fk), job_id(fk), date_joined
>
> > **lr_ranks:** rank_id(pk), name

```
$qry= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT lr_users.username, lr_users.rank, lr_users.job_id, lr_users.date_joined lr_ranks.name AS rankname FROM lr_users 
    LEFT JOIN lr_ranks ON lr_users.rank = lr_ranks.rank_id")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
```

Above is my PHP code for generating a 'LEFT JOIN' query, however when I run it i get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.name AS rankname FROM lr_users LEFT JOIN lr_ranks ON lr_users.rank = lr_ran' at line 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: simple syntax error.  you need a  comma between these two keys:   `lr_users.date_joined lr_ranks.name`

Comment: I recommend deleting this post, as it is not helpful to future users

Comment: unfortunately I can't delete the post since it has already been answered :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error (comma missing before `lr_users.date_joined`):

```
$qry= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT lr_users.username, lr_users.rank, lr_users.job_id, lr_users.date_joined, lr_ranks.name AS rankname FROM lr_users 
    LEFT JOIN lr_ranks ON lr_users.rank = lr_ranks.rank_id")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you formatted your code more legibly, this kind of error wouldn't arise:

```
$query = "
SELECT u.username
     , u.rank
     , u.job_id
     , u.date_joined 
     , r.name rankname 
  FROM lr_users u
  LEFT 
  JOIN lr_ranks r
    ON u.rank = r.rank_id;
";
```